# Multiple database dependencies is causing to connect database in Quarkus

Tags: java, quarkus

I have two environments like onprem and aws, for
onprem we have connected with Oracle database and required configuration
is done and but for aws we are using aurora postgres and whenever
i have tried to add postgres dependency then deploying into
aws environment it's giving error so is it possible if we have
multiple dependencies in same pom file and used for different environments.

```
Quarks version : 1.13.3.final
Sample configuration:

Oracle:
-------
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=oracle
quarkus.datasource.username=user-default
quarkus.datasource.password=password-default
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=jdbc:oracle:thin://localhost:5432/default

Postgresql:
-----------
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql 
quarkus.datasource.username=user-default
quarkus.datasource.password=password-default
quarkus.datasource.reactive.url=postgresql://localhost:5432/default
```

Code or issue:
The issue i'm getting is as follows:

```
2021-11-11 07:18:45,173 WARN [org.hib.eng.jdb.env.int.JdbcEnvironmentInitiator] (main) HHH000342: Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.sql.SQLException: Driver does not support the provided URL: jdbc:postgresql://
        at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.connectionSetup(ConnectionFactory.java:220)
            at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionFactory.createConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:204)
            at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:490)
            at io.agroal.pool.ConnectionPool$CreateConnectionTask.call(ConnectionPool.java:472)
```

---

```
Dependencies:
quarkus-jdbc-oracle
quarkus-jdbc-postgresql
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the official documentation, you can use Multiple Datasources.
However if you **have more than 1**, then you must provide a **Name**, otherwise how will Quarkus know which Drivers to use.

The format : `quarkus.datasource.<datasourceCustomName>.`  If it is not your default DataSource which will not require a name.

Important to Notice: `For now, multiple datasources are only supported for JDBC and the Agroal extension. So it is not currently possible to create multiple reactive datasources.`

https://quarkus.io/guides/datasource#multiple-datasources

**Multiple Datasources**

> Configuring Multiple Datasources
>
> For now, multiple datasources are only supported for JDBC and the
> Agroal extension. So it is not currently possible to create multiple
> reactive datasources.
>
> The Hibernate ORM extension supports defining several persistence
> units using configuration properties. For each persistence unit, you
> can point to the datasource of your choice.
>
> Defining multiple datasources works exactly the same way as defining a
> single datasource, with one important change: you define a name.

In the following example, you have 3 different datasources:

1. The default one,
2. A datasource named users,
3. A datasource named inventory,

each with its own configuration.

```
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=h2
quarkus.datasource.username=username-default
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:default
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=13

quarkus.datasource.users.db-kind=h2
quarkus.datasource.users.username=username1
quarkus.datasource.users.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:users
quarkus.datasource.users.jdbc.max-size=11

quarkus.datasource.inventory.db-kind=h2
quarkus.datasource.inventory.username=username2
quarkus.datasource.inventory.jdbc.url=jdbc:h2:mem:inventory
quarkus.datasource.inventory.jdbc.max-size=12
```

Comment: Thanks for the response but i have only one datasource i.e like default datasource existing it has oracle and able to connect to the database into all environments. So i have a new requirement to implement same changes into AWS environment and we have created config and deployment files accordingly but it needs to connect aurora postgres database for that i have included one more dependency called quarkus-jdbc-postgres then while deploying into AWS environment its unable to identifying the driver and we don't have multiple datasources in a same file. it has follows only.

Comment: we don't need any reactive datasource and always it has single default datasource with respective environment and two dependencies.
quarkus.datasource.db-kind=postgresql 
quarkus.datasource.username=user-default
quarkus.datasource.password=password-default
quarkus.datasource.jdbc.max-size=13

if we have added two dependencies at the same time then it's causing of failed to connect the database and it's throwing following exception.

Could not obtain connection to query metadata: java.sql.SQLException: Driver does not support the provided URL: jdbc:postgresql://

Answer (score 0):

`quarkus.datasource.db-kind` is fixed at build time. The property can not change at runtime.

You have to build the app for Oracle and seperate for Postgresql

https://quarkus.io/guides/all-config#quarkus-datasource_quarkus.datasource.db-kind